# React context not updated from child functional component with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

CONTEXT: Game board with square tiles. Units sit outside the board and on game start, user is allowed to drag and drop units on a given tile. I am trying to keep track of tiles X,Y values in the App context so that I can tell on which tile a unit has been dropped.

Ideally, when component mounts (Tile.js), it spreads the context by adding it's own position as an object with useEffect.

```
App.js
```

```
import { Encampment } from "./components/Encampment";
import "./App.css";
import { Battlefield } from "./components/Battlefield";
import { Unit } from "./components/Unit";
import { ARMY } from "./constants";
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const CoordsContext = createContext<{
  tilesCoords: object[];
  setTilesCoords: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<object[]>>;
}>({
  tilesCoords: [],
  setTilesCoords: () => {},
});

function App() {
  //  TODO: set tiles coordinates as context to control if unit dropped on it. https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#updating-data-passed-via-context

  const [tilesCoords, setTilesCoords] = useState<object[]>([]);

  const armyColours = ["black", "white"];

  let whiteArmy: React.ReactElement[] = [];
  let balckArmy: React.ReactElement[] = [];

  armyColours.forEach((colour) => {
    Object.entries(ARMY).forEach((entries) => {
      const [ObjKey, value] = entries;
      for (let index = 0; index < value; index++) {
        const name = `${ObjKey}-${colour}`;
        const key = `${name}_${index}`;
        colour === "white"
          ? whiteArmy.push(<Unit name={name} key={key} />)
          : balckArmy.push(<Unit name={name} key={key} />);
      }
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CoordsContext.Provider value={{ tilesCoords, setTilesCoords }}>
        <Encampment units={whiteArmy} />
        <Battlefield />
        <Encampment units={balckArmy} />
      </CoordsContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
Tile.js
```

```
import { FC, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles/Tile.css";
import { TileProps } from "../types/TileProps";
import { CoordsContext } from "../App";
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";

const BLUE = "#4364db";
const GREEN = "#6cbc6c";
const YELLOW = "#b8b877";
const BROWN = "#8d5a5a";
const BLACK = "black";

const Tile: FC<TileProps> = ({ terrain, isHill, children }) => {
  const tileRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const getPosition = () => {
    if (tileRef.current) {
      const x = tileRef.current.offsetLeft;
      const y = tileRef.current.offsetTop;
      return [x, y];
    }
  };
  const context = useRef(useContext(CoordsContext));
  const { tilesCoords, setTilesCoords } = context.current;

  useEffect(() => {
    const position = getPosition();
    console.log('position', position)
    console.log('children', children)
    console.log("tilesCoords", tilesCoords);
    setTilesCoords([...tilesCoords, { position, key: children }]);
    // need to pass dependencies but in a way that doesn't cause infinite loop
  }, []);

  let backgroundColor;
  switch (terrain) {
    case "water":
      backgroundColor = BLUE;
      break;
    case "grass":
      backgroundColor = GREEN;
      break;
    case "sand":
      backgroundColor = YELLOW;
      break;
    case "dirt":
      backgroundColor = BROWN;
      break;
    case "mount":
      backgroundColor = BLACK;
      break;
  }

  const outline = isHill ? "2px solid black" : "none";
  const zIndex = isHill ? 2 : 0;

  const tileStyle = {
    backgroundColor,
    outline,
    zIndex,
  };

  return <div className="tile" style={tileStyle} ref={tileRef}></div>;
};

export default Tile;
```

RESULT: Context contains always only the last tile coords.

Below you can see the Context inside the React Developer Tools
[image: Components]

And the logs
[image: Logs]

N.B.

- I am using useRef to wrap context accessed inside Tile, but I get same result without using it
- Adding dependencies to useEffect causes infinite loop (adding always last tile coords anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside `useEffect` in `Tile.js`. Instead of doing

```
setTilesCoords([...tilesCoords, { position, key: children }]);
```

I should have used the current state parameter received

```
setTilesCoords((state) => [...state, { position, key: children }]);
```

As specified in the [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)